# Nav bar tabs in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I'm trying to design the nav bar of the website I'm building. I include the code below, but I cannot figure out how to get the nav bar options to appear like a folder tab. See this image:

[image]

I don't understand how to do this with HTML and CSS. What I have at the moment is:

HTML

```css
nav {
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: lightskyblue;
  background-color: royalblue;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 180%;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border: 5px;
  border-colour: red;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: lightskyblue;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>

    <li>
      <a class="active" href="http://www.google.com/ncr">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.google.com/ncr">Full list of Articles</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.google.com/ncr">Disciplines</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.google.com/ncr">More Resources</a></li>
    <li> <a class="about" href="http://www.google.com/ncr">About Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below, I have created an offsett on the main 'ul' and set the 'li' items above it using "top: -41px" and "position: relative".

Then, using JavaScript, I added eventlisteners to each of the list items, that when hovered over will change the 'ul' background color.

Obviously the styling needs some work but that is something you should try to do yourself.

Please see below:

```js
//event listeners for the 'hovers'
document.getElementById("firstitem").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("list").style.backgroundColor = "royalblue";
});

document.getElementById("seconditem").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("list").style.backgroundColor = "pink";
});

document.getElementById("thirditem").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("list").style.backgroundColor = "green";
});

document.getElementById("fourthitem").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("list").style.backgroundColor = "red";
});

document.getElementById("fifthitem").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("list").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
nav {
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: lightskyblue;
  background-color: royalblue;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 180%;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 41px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border: 5px;
  top: -41px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-color: red;
}

li:first-child {
  background-color: royalblue;
  }

li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: pink;
  }
  
li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  }
  
li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: red;
  }
  
li:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: yellow;
  }
  
a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(108, 162, 196);
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul id="list">
      
          <li id="firstitem">
            <a class="active" href="http://www.google.com/ncr">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li id="seconditem"> <a href="http://www.google.com/ncr">Full list of Articles</a></li>
          <li id="thirditem"> <a href="http://www.google.com/ncr">Disciplines</a></li>
          <li id="fourthitem"> <a href="http://www.google.com/ncr">More Resources</a></li>
          <li id="fifthitem"> <a class="about" href="http://www.google.com/ncr">About Me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```